# How to import multiple stylesheets with @Import

Tags: tapestry

Currently I have this above my class:

```
@Import(stylesheet="context:/styles/stylesheet1.css")
```

But I need to import more styles for this page.

How can I import more than one stylesheet with @Import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
@Import(stylesheet = {"path-to-stylesheet","path-to-stylesheet"})
```